# Soma de strings em PHP e JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Me deparei com este problema e entrei em conflito, quando se usa '+' no JavaScript ele "junta" e no PHP ele me resulta um número (Oi?), bom a intençao é adequar o **JavaScript com o PHP**, veja:

```
alert(CryptoJS.SHA1('ABCDE' + 'ABCD'.substr(0, 32)));
result: 64b9885c4ab720cabee37f0011aeb06efa27f9b3
```

[Disponivel aqui.](http://jsfiddle.net/rrododrb/)

No PHP eu executo a "mesma" coisa, porém retorna algo diferente:

```
echo SHA1('ABCDE' + substr('ABCD', 0, 32));
result: b6589fc6ab0dc82cf12099d1c2d40ab994e8410c
```

**Por que**? Qual a explicaçao para isso e como adequar o JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

O PHP e o javascript possuem operadores diferentes para a operação de concatenar strings.
Em javascript, use "**+**"; em PHP, use "**.**"

```
echo SHA1('ABCDE' . substr('ABCD', 0, 32));
```

Comment: a intençao é adequar o JS ao PHP.. e por que está acontecendo isso? preciso entender pra nao errar mais.. Obg!

Comment: Está acontecendo porque cada uma dessas linguagens tem um operador diferente para trabalhar com a concatenação de strings. Não é questão de adequar, uma usa o "ponto" e a outra o "sinal de mais", só isso.

Comment: Os operadores de concatenação são diferentes para cada linguagem. php o operador é . enquanto que nos js é o +